# Universal links stopped working after bundle was changed

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

Universal links were integrated and working both on dev and prod environments.

Then we moved the app to another dev account. (It has not been released yet. So, just another dev account was created, another bundle for the project was set.)

Universal links stopped working.

We did

- update AASA file to contain new team id + bundle id
- enable Associated Domains for the new App Id
- regenerate provisioning profiles
- make sure .entitlements file exists, contains domains and is added to bundle resources (to be included into the target).

I tried to list all possible domains inside .entitlements file, but to no luck.

- domain.com
- *.domain.com
- deeplink.domain.com
- *.deeplink.domain.com

etc

We checked AASA file with this validator

https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/#resultsbox

It shows success.

Still, universal links don't work.

I will be happy to receive ANY hint as to where to look and check.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this counts as the accepted answer, but universal links just started working. Nothing changed compared to how it was before. They didn't work in the evening, they started working in the morning (after 2 days of trying to find the reason).